# Existence of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove / disprove the existence of a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T\neq 0$ and:
$$T^3=-T$$
This should be pretty easy but for some reason I just can’t figure it out.

Hints will be much appreciated!

Comment: Zero transformation is one example.

Comment: Except zero... I forgot to mention it

Comment: Your are looking for any $3\times 3$ matrix $T$ such that $T^3+T=0$; so (by Cayley-Hamilton) the characteristic polynomial satisfying $x^3+x=0$ works. Hope you can take it from there to construct nontrivial ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment above, any singular matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} a&b&0\\c&-a&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ with $bc+a^2=-1$ satisfies your hypothesis.

Comment: Great, even though it is so simple, that's exaclty what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the concept of a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), which given a monic polynomial $f$, provides a square matrix $T$ of dimension equal to the degree of $f$, whose charcteristic polynomial is equal to $f$.

Since $T^3 + T = 0$, a matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^3+x$ satisfies the requirements of the question, by the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) , so long as that matrix is non-zero.

Therefore, by the companion matrix construction, we write our polynomial as $0+1x+0x^2+x^3$, and the resulting companion matrix is :
$$
T = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer I really appreciate it! However, I was looking for a solution that uses more basic concepts. This question was given in the final exam of a fundamental course in linear algebra, the students shouldn't be familiar yet with the companion matrix, and eigenvalues in general.

Comment: You are welcome! The concept of a companion matrix will be able to help you solve these and similar questions easily. I hope this helps you in a more advanced course in linear algebra if you take one. +1 to your question.

Comment: I actually have only one semester to graduate, so I am familiar with the concepts :) (I have even seen how to derive this matrix using module theory!) I asked this question since I am going to help the first year students, and I think this is a nice exercise for them, but even though I am familiar with this matrix, I still didn't come up with the answer myself, which is indeed really elegant!